# Why does the pion not undergo netural particle oscillation?

Tags: particle-physics, cp-violation

$K$, $B$ and now $D$ mesons exhibit [neutral particle oscillation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_particle_oscillation), where we see the spontaneous interchange between a particle and its antiparticle, i.e. $K^0 \Leftrightarrow \overline{K}^0$, $B^0 \Leftrightarrow \overline{B}^0$ and $D^0 \Leftrightarrow \overline{D}^0$.

My question is, why do neutral pions $\pi^0$ **not** exhibit the same behaviour? We never hear of "pion oscillation" $\pi^0 \Leftrightarrow \overline{\pi}^0$...

Comment: because pi0 is its own antiparticle, there  is no quantum number to differentiate the particle from the antiparticle

Comment: Isn't the $K^0$ also its own antiparticle? Same for the $B^0$?

Comment: No, the neutral  K's have opposite strangness

Comment: What about the $B^0$?

Comment: Yes neutral B are similar to K They have the beauty quantum number. The D have the charm

Comment: and there is no associated quantum number with the $u$ or with the $d$?

Comment: No. no quantum number that has to be respected and can oscillate due to an interaction that does not respect it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_particle_oscillation

Comment: Thanks. Is there any theory that explains why there are quantum numbers for every quark *but* for the *u* and the *d*?

Comment: @SuperCiocia The u and d quarks make up the strong isospin doublet; that quantum number transforms differently from strangeness etc. I suspect the reason is that the u and d are both light compared to the hadrons they make up, while the other quarks are heavier.  That would be an interesting follow-up question.

Comment: You could say that the up and down quarks have their own quantum number. Up quarks have +1 upness, and down quarks have -1 downness. Neutral pions have 0 upness and 0 downness (and 0 of every other quark quantum number). See Griffiths' particle book, 2nd ed. p. 49.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer transposed from a comment: the $K$, $D$, $B$ have nonzero "flavor quantum number" (strangeness, charm, and beauty, to be specific). The analogy you should pursue is the $J/\psi$ or "charmonium," made of a charm quark and charm anti-quark.