# What is the symmetry of the doublet ($u$, $d$)?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, standard-model, quarks, isospin-symmetry

The up quark $u$ and down quark $d$ form a doublet ($u$, $d$). I know that they have a SU(2) symmetry. However, they also have a U(1) symmetry because they are regarded as two states of the same type of particle. I am puzzled: What is the symmetry of this doublet? Do they have two symmetries, i.e., SU(2) and U(1), or U(2) = SU(2) $\otimes$ U(1)? How to understand their symmetry?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175667/2451

Comment: Yes, they have those two symmetries as direct product. Additionally, they have SU(3) color symmetry, as well. So they form $SU(2)_L$ doublet of $SU(3)_C$ triplets with $U(1)_Y$ hypercharge. Leptons, on the other hand, are color singlets.

Comment: In fact, $u$ and $d$ have different masses. So, is the $S(2)_{L}$ flavor symmetry broken or not exact?